# Recursive Group->Subgroup content (entity reference) relationship with Organic Groups and views

Tags: views, entities, organic-groups

I have Organic Groups in Drupal 7 setup. I have two OG content types: Topic and Project. Topic is a regular OG group. Topic is both an OG Group and Group Content, so it is a subgroup, which can reference Topic. 
I have a panel page setup that displays the Topic groups nicely, including a view that displays all content that is a member of that specific Topic group. This (as intended) also lists all Project groups that are a member of the specific Topic.

Now the question: is it also possible to add recursion to this Group Content view, where I don't only show the content that is a member of the particular Topic, but also of the child Projects of the Topic.

If I understand correctly the Group memberships depend on entity reference, so this would boil down to views being able to recurse through entity references.

I hope this is possible because it would greatly improve the user experience of my site where now a user has to both reference the subgroup and the parent group if they add content to a subgroup, in order for it to show up on the parent group.